# How to delete picture from Firebase Storage

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I have an app, that has many users they are all stored in Realtime Database. I'm trying to delete user on button click with all the data, but the profile pictures are still left in Firebase Storage after deletion. So when I try to delete the picture from Firebase Storage aswell as users I get this error.
 User does not have permission to access this object.

So I'm trying to delete picture in the ValueEventListener method, because I can easily get the ImageURL from my Realtime Database.

Realtime Database

In DB I have attribute profileimage: GeneratedPictureUrlWhenUploadingToStorage
Also my pictures in Firebase Storage are named currentUserId + ".JPG" so its like an indetifer

Storage Rules:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Code:

```
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.buttonEditProfile:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, ProfileEditActivity.class));
            break;
        case R.id.buttonUserList:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, UserListActivity.class));
            break;
        case R.id.buttonDeleteAccount:

            profileUserRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                        StorageReference storageReference1;
                        String myImage = dataSnapshot.child("profileimage").getValue().toString();
                        storageReference1 = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(myImage);
                        storageReference1.delete();
                    }


                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

            DatabaseReference drFailure = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("failures").child(currentUserId);
            DatabaseReference drVehicles = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("vehicles").child(currentUserId);
            DatabaseReference drUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users").child(currentUserId);
            FirebaseUser userDel = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

            drFailure.removeValue();
            drVehicles.removeValue();
            drUsers.removeValue();
            userDel.delete();
```

When I press the buttonDeleteAccount I want to delete Storaged pictures of uniqe User

Comment: "Use `android-studio` for questions about using Android Studio. Do NOT use for questions about programming for Android in general; instead use the `android` tag."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting an error with permission, maybe the storage rules is blocking your access.

Also try to delete the file using your file name logic.
Like:

```js
StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();
StorageReference photoRef = storageRef.child("YOUR_PATH" + userId + ".jpg");

photoRef.delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
        // Success
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
       // Error
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also change your rules
if you don't have firebase code from:

```
service firebase.storage {
match /b/{bucket}/o {
match /{allPaths=**} {
allow read, write: if
request.auth != null;
}
}
}
```

To:

```
service firebase.storage {
match /b/{bucket}/o {
match /{allPaths=**} {
allow read, write;
}
}
}
```

Just make sure you change it back after you get your code from firebase

Answer (score 0):

I did the same but it's working serious on retrieving data from firebase

```
retrieveUserInfo();

userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(currentUserId);
    private void retrieveUserInfo() {
        String currentUserId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(currentUserId);
        userRef.keepSynced(true);
        userRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if((snapshot.exists()) &&  (snapshot.hasChild("image")) ){
                    StorageReference storageReference1;

                    String retrieveProfileImage = snapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();
                    String retrieveUserName = snapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();


                    storageReference1 = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(retrieveProfileImage);
                    storageReference1.delete();
                    Toast.makeText(ImageActivity.this, "Welcome!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    Picasso.get().load(retrieveProfileImage).placeholder(R.drawable.pro_pic).into(imageView);
                    textView.setText(retrieveUserName);

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```